# images aren't transitioning in a smooth way, i can't figure out why it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been out of web development for a long time, and I'm super rusty. I'm working on a website for myself so I've gone to GPT for assistance. It's all been going well, but I'm trying to have background images fade in and out; as far as I can tell the setup I've got works in principal but it just isn't achieving the smooth transition I had in mind.

```js
window.onload = changeBackgroundImage;

var imageIndex = 1;
var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var imagePath = isMobile ? 'assets/img/mobBg/' : 'assets/img/bg/';
var imageExtension = '.png';
var errorCount = 0;

function changeBackgroundImage() {
  var currentBg = document.getElementById('bg1');
  var nextBg = document.getElementById('bg2');

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = imagePath + imageIndex + imageExtension;
  console.log('Loading image:', img.src);
  img.onload = function() {
    nextBg.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img.src + ')';
    setTimeout(function() {
      currentBg.style.opacity = '0'; // Start the fade-out of the current image
    }, 7000); // Start the fade-out after 7 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      var temp = currentBg;
      currentBg.style.zIndex = '1'; // Move the current image underneath
      nextBg.style.zIndex = '2'; // Bring the next image to the top
      currentBg.style.opacity = '1'; // Reset the opacity of the current image
      currentBg = nextBg;
      nextBg = temp;
      imageIndex++;
    }, 10000); // Swap the images after 10 seconds (the duration of the fade-out plus 3 seconds)
    errorCount = 0; // Reset error count on successful load
    setTimeout(changeBackgroundImage, 10000); // Change image every 10 seconds
  };
  img.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Failed to load image:', img.src);
    if (errorCount < 10) { // If less than 10 consecutive errors
      errorCount++;
      imageIndex++;
      changeBackgroundImage();
    } else { // If 10 or more consecutive errors
      errorCount = 0;
      imageIndex = 1;
      changeBackgroundImage();
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#bg1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
  /* bg1 is initially on top */
}

#bg2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  /* bg2 is initially underneath */
}
```

```html
<div id="bg1" class="bg visible"></div>
<!-- Add the 'visible' class to 'bg1' -->
<div id="bg2" class="bg hidden"></div>
<!-- Add the 'hidden' class to 'bg2' -->
```

Sorry it's a lot, thanks in advance :)

I tried changing the values(`transition`, `timeout`, etc), I'm currently using solid color images to make it more obvious, red, green, and blue. but the images just look to change abruptly.

Comment: I've converted your code to a runnable snippet, in order that those viewing the question can see the code in action without having to create their own reproduction. Your code generates a lot of errors, due to to missing assets. Can you please address those issues (perhaps with links to images hosted at, for example, https://picsum.photos)?

Answer (score 0):

Z-index works instantly, that is why you do not see any transition for the opacity. As a cure `eventListener` on `transitionend` of the opacity might help https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event.

Its something like

```
const zIndexHandler = (evt) => {
 currentBg.removeEventListener('transitionend',zIndexHandler)
 var temp = currentBg; 
 currentBg.style.zIndex = '1'; // Move the current image underneath
 nextBg.style.zIndex = '2'; // Bring the next image to the top
 currentBg = nextBg;
 nextBg = temp;
 imageIndex++;
};

setTimeout(function() {
  currentBg.style.opacity = '1'; // Reset the opacity of the current image
  currentBg.addEventListener('transitionend',zIndexHandler)
      
}, 10000); // Swap the images after 10 seconds (the duration of the fade-out plus 3 seconds)
```

Or maybe you do not need to change z-index at all